# Why does scrollWidth only include the left padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, cssom

So, I have a DIV `#Wrapper` which has a fixed width. Inside that DIV, I have another DIV `#Panel` which also has a fixed width:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <p>...</p>
    <div id="Panel">Panel</div>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Sometimes, the width of the Panel is larger than the with of the Wrapper, and in those cases I would like to widen the Wrapper via JavaScript, so that it wraps the Panel perfectly.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/H6rML/

I intended to use `.scrollWidth` on the Wrapper to determine the width of the Panel. However, the problem is that the Wrapper has horizontal padding, and the `.scrollWidth` for some reason only includes the left-padding of the wrapper. So:

```
Wrapper.scrollWidth === Wrapper.LeftPadding + Panel.Width
```

So, given:

```
#Wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;        
}

#Panel {
    width: 300px;
}
```

`Wrapper.scrollWidth` returns `310px`, which is not very useful. If `.scrollWidth` didn't include any padding and only returned the width of the Panel, I could work with that (I would add the padding manually to that value). If both paddings were included, I could work with that too. But why is only the left padding included? (Btw this behavior appears to be cross-browser.)

A few additional notes:

1. I cannot set the width on the Wrapper directly. In my actual code, I set the width on an ancestor element that is several levels above the Wrapper, and I use a custom API to set the width. This is why I need to retrieve the full `320px` value.
2. I would like a solution that does not depend on the content of the Wrapper. In my demo it's a Panel, but in other scenarios there could be a different element that overflows, or even multiple elements. That is why I went with `.scrollWidth` on the Wrapper.

Is there a way to get the value `320px` without having to manually add the right padding to the `.scrollWidth` value?

---

Btw, according to the standard, the right padding should be included:

> The scrollWidth attribute must return the result of running these
>   steps:
>
> 1. If the element does not have any associated CSS layout box return zero and terminate these steps.
> 2. If the element is the root element and the Document is not in quirks mode return max(document content width, value of innerWidth).
> 3. If the element is the HTML body element and the Document is in quirks mode return max(document content width, value of innerWidth).
> 4. **Return the computed value of the 'padding-left' property, plus the computed value of the 'padding-right', plus the content width of the element.**

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/

Why don't the browsers behave accordingly?

---

To further improve the clarity of my post, let me sum up the two main questions:

(1) If the standard states that the right padding should be included in the `.scrollWidth` value, then why don't the browsers behave accordingly?

(2) Is it possible to retrieve the correct value (`320px` in my case), without having to manually add the right padding?

---

## This question has been answered in another thread

The answer to this question is located here: [When a child element overflows horizontally, why is the right padding of the parent ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054870/when-a-child-element-overflows-horizontally-why-is-the-right-padding-of-the-par)

​

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I cannot set the width on the Wrapper directly. Please read the comments below Elliot's answer. I will update my question in order to clarify that.

Comment: Why you need to recalculate the `#Wrapper` width? After `#Panel` is perfectly wrapped, I would not bother more :)

Comment: P.S: you really cannot use jQ for that purpose? http://jsfiddle.net/ytByf/1/  using `.outerWidth(true)` it returns '320' ! Hope that helps! (Hello to Zagreb.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan As I said, I do *not* set the width on the Wrapper, but on an outer element (an ancestor that is further up the DOM tree). I have a custom function which sets the width on that ancestor, and in order for it to correctly set the width, I have to pass the value `320` to it. `Wrapper.scrollWidth` (incorrectly?) returns the value `310` (it doesn't include the right padding), so I have to figure out how to deal with this issue. (Pozdrav `:)`)

Comment: Kind of interesting, looks like there's no easy way to calculate BOTH paddings. Even with jQuery we have to use strictly 'padding-left' (or other) to get the computed padding (native) value.  http://jsbin.com/onufey/edit#javascript,html,live  But here it's achieved: http://jsbin.com/onufey/2/edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I could add the right padding to the `.scrollWidth` value; that would work. The question is, why isn't the right padding included in `.scrollWidth`. The standard states that it should be.

Comment: Ah, I see now in the docs. And you bolded it. I'll look further to that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but from what I read, I assume you want to change width of #Wrapper based on #Panel. In that case, maybe you could try the following:

```
#Wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    make sure to remove width from #Wrapper
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why leading browsers share this bug up until today, but here is a **demo of the problem and `inline-block` workaround**.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += 'one.scrollWidth = '+ document.querySelector('.one').scrollWidth 
                          +'<br>two.scrollWidth = '+ document.querySelector('.two').scrollWidth
                          +'<br>three.scrollWidth = '+ document.querySelector('.three').scrollWidth
                          +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(fix applied to grand children)<br>four.scrollWidth = '+ document.querySelector('.four').scrollWidth +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(fix applied to direct child)';
```

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid rgba(50,150,220,1);
}
.child{
  background:rgba(100,200,255,0.3);
  padding:10px 20px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.scroll-container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.two, .three, .four{
  width:60px;
}
.three .child{
  display:inline-block;
}
.four .parent{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container one">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="scroll-container two">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="scroll-container three">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="scroll-container four">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Wrapper {
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left; 
}
```

or use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = jQuery("#Panel").width();
    $("#Wrapper").width(width);
});
```

Comment: Switching the element to a float is a relatively big change, that may introduce issues with the existing CSS/JavaScript code, so I see it only as an eventual last resort...

Comment: Can you use jquery method above?  Why is floating it left such a drastic change?

Comment: Are you able to use jquery like the solution above?

Comment: When an element is floated, it is removed from the page flow. There are various differences between in-flow and out-of-flow elements: they are laid out differently, different CSS properties apply differently (different algorithms are used to determine the computed value) or don't apply at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Wrapper").width($("#Panel").outerWidth());
});
```

This takes into account `#Panel`'s padding, margins, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not setting the width on the Wrapper itself. The code in my answer is a simplified version of my actual code. In my code I have several layers of wrappers (one of them being an iframe), and the width is set via a third-party API (not jQuery). Therefore, I need to determine the correct value (`320px` in my example above).

Comment: Replace 'Wrapper' with the ID of the element you are setting the width of, then, right?

Comment: That wouldn't work because your code doesn't take into account the padding of the Wrapper. The value of `$("#Panel").outerWidth()` is `300`, but the value that I need is `320`. In the special case when you set the width on the Wrapper itself, you can use the value `300`, but if you set the width on an outer element (you need to take into account the horizontal padding of the Wrapper).

Comment: Maybe you want to set `$("#Wrapper").innerWidth()` instead.

Comment: `.innerWidth()` cannot be set; it is a read-only method. As I said, I don't set the width on the Wrapper, but on an outer element. This cannot be changed.

Comment: Mm. Well, sorry I couldn't help you. Good luck.