# When a child element overflows horizontally, why is the right padding of the parent ignored?

Tags: html, css, browser, overflow

Given this simple structure:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#child {
    width: 500px;      
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/523me/5/

Notice that the parent has a `20px` padding and that the child overflows horizontally (because it is wider). If you scroll the parent all the way to the right, you'll see that the child touches the right edge of the parent.

So, the parent should have a right padding, but it is ignored. It seems that when the child has a fixed width, the right padding of the parent does not apply. (Is this specified by a standard? I would love to know. Please let me know if you find anything!)

Is there a way to force the right padding to be applied in this scenario *without* having to remove any of the elements from the flow (by floating or positioning)?

[image]

Screenshot 1 - The right padding is ignored. This is how all current browsers behave.

Screenshot 2 - The right padding applies. This is what I'm trying to accomplish. (Btw, the screenshot is from IE7, which is the only browser which does not ignore the right padding.)

Comment: Is this issue still happening?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're suffering from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170707053030/http://www.brunildo.org/test/overscrollback.html) problem.

I would solve it by giving a margin to the child (and not a padding to the parent):

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: gray;
}

#child {
  width: 500px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et turpis eu lorem consectetur blandit sed vel ligula. In lorem ligula, lacinia sed aliquet sed, congue quis tortor. In sed magna eros, eget blandit arcu. Nulla sit amet volutpat ipsum. Duis
    quis nisl massa. Sed ipsum magna, tempus non malesuada in, gravida et sapien. Fusce a odio nulla, quis ultrices mauris. Maecenas in tellus id massa fringilla molestie.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is interesting that it needs the `inline-block` to work, as `block` [does not do it](http://jsfiddle.net/fwTAS/1/), yet one would think it would. +1 for the link showing research.

Comment: @ScottS Yeah, it's the damn browsers, they all have their own interpretations of the CSS specification, as much as they try to uphold it (except the non-standard rogue mess that is IE). `block` and its buddy `inline-block` should share all of their box-model features and differentiate only by inline-block's way of not obstructing page flow and mingling with inline stuff. I'd certainly like to find out more about this specific behavior.

Comment: @Jota `display:inline-block` risks having two children with small content appear side-by-side: http://jsfiddle.net/523me/20/ +1 from me also for the link.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas--depending on your application intentions, you could [solve the small content issue](http://jsfiddle.net/523me/21/) with a `min-width`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, that case! Maybe maintaining the *blockiness* of the child and give it a container for its content: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joaope/j4NNC/)

Comment: This particular behavior of `display` is an enormous grey area from the spec to its implementation on browsers. `inline-block` rocks as much as it sucks. If you play around with `white-space` you might also get the expected behavior. Again, grey area!

Comment: but i have margin-auto on child :// what do i do?

Answer (score 9):

Dunno but adding:

```
#child{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/523me/6/

I've only tested in latest Chrome, may not be cross-browser

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, inline-block is used to place block elements directly/inline with the text (or inline elements), intermixing it. So the parent block might resolve it as it would *regular text*, and relative to it, parent padding goes the evident 20px around it. But this is more of a hack, that's why it doesn't work in Firefox. Its usage is for specific logical cases where such a layout is preferable.

Answer (score 9):

You might change the padding to a border.

```
padding: 20px;
```

to

```
border: 20px solid gray;
```

Comment: The border wraps the scroll-bar which does not look good: http://jsfiddle.net/523me/17/

Comment: This workaround worked for me. I set the border color to a trasparent one. Upvoted!

Comment: yeah transparent border is still elegant and readable code than having another else, thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, the padding is not ignored, but it's still inside the parent.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/523me/8/), where you can see that the padding hasn't moved from its original position.

Edit: Hm, there are some anomalies. If you give the inner div a right margin, that gets ignored too. Hm. Upvoting your question.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, it is what it is, but I don't like it. I would be happier if the padding of the parent were wrapped around the widest child, instead of applying only to those children which don't have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Apply padding-right to overflowing element itself, and move background to its direct child element.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"><div>Lorem ipsum...</div></div>
</div>

<style>
#parent {padding-right: 0; }
#child {padding-right: 20px; }
#child > DIV {background: yellow; }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/523me/9/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a right margin to the last child.  Something like:

```
shared-client-logos shared-client-logo:last-of-type img {
margin-right: 20px; }
```

I know this works because I've just used it (this will add 20px margin to the right of any image within the last shared-client-logo element within the shared-client-logos tag).

Answer (score 0):

Alternativrely you can make flex container:

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 12px;
}
#child {
  background: yellow;
  width: 5000px;  
  height: 100%;   
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="child">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```